# $\lim_{x\to \infty}\arcsin\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\arcsin\frac{1-x}{1+x}$$

using $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arcsin}{x}=1$,
using a change the variable like $t=\frac{1}{x}$, did't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the continuity of arcsin,  I think you can say that your limit is equal to

$$\arcsin \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$$

Comment: Not sure why you changed the denominator, but I suppose you get the right answer by doing that.

Comment: @J.G. So sorry about that! Just corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Find the limit of $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ when $x \to\infty $